# using SCL in the command call for Ruby script

Tags: ruby, file, software-collections

My employer has Ruby 1.8.7 in the /usr/bin/ruby, and allows the usage of Ruby 2.4 only via SCL (sofoware collections).

 Which means that when I run ruby, I need to use (from the RH6 shell) `scl enablde ruby-24 'ruby foo.rb'` when `foo.rb`
is the file name.
I want to enable the ruby call on the first execution line, i.e., instead of the Ruby code file looking like:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
puts "Hello world"
```

That the code will look

```
#!cmd
puts "Hello world"
```

Where the cmd is what calls via the `scl` and run the Ruby 2.4  for the `puts` command. I know that a wrapper file can be used. I want something in 1 file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```ruby
#!/usr/bin/ruby
if RUBY_VERSION != "2.4.1"
  exec "scl enable ruby-24; ruby __FILE__"
end
puts "Ruby Version: #{RUBY_VERSION}"
```